# Text opacity changing font weight

Tags: css

I'm using two Google fonts (Montserrat & Bitter) for text content. Without changing opacity, the text is rendered far too heavily. However setting `opacity: .99` or lower displays the text in the assigned font-weight. Issue is visible in Chrome and Safari.

Tried `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` though no change.

Anyway to have the text display normally without the opacity property?

http://cl.ly/image/2f2V0h1R1r3H

```
h1 {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 1.7em;
font-weight: 400;
text-shadow: 0px 2px 6px black;
line-height: 1.1em;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

p {
font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: 400;
text-shadow: 0px 2px 6px black;
line-height: 1.2em;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

http://cl.ly/image/2s173l270z2S

```
h1 {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 1.7em;
font-weight: 400;
text-shadow: 0px 2px 6px black;
line-height: 1.1em;
opacity: .99;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

p {
font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: 400;
text-shadow: 0px 2px 6px black;
line-height: 1.2em;
opacity: .99;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: Please provide fiddle